# How to assign tasks to specific worker within Dask.Distributed

Tags: dask-distributed

I am interesting in using Dask Distributed as task executor.
In Celery it is possible to assign task to specific worker. How is it possible using Dask Distributed?

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 options:

1. [Specify workers by name](https://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/locality.html?highlight=client.submit) or host or IP (but only positive declarations):

   ```
   dask-worker scheduler_address:8786 --name worker_1
   ```

   and then one of option:

   ```
   client.map(func, sequence, workers='worker_1')
   client.map(func, sequence, workers=['192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.100:8989', 'alice', 'alice:8989'])
   client.submit(f, x, workers='127.0.0.1')
   client.submit(f, x, workers='127.0.0.1:55852')
   client.submit(f, x, workers=['192.168.1.101', '192.168.1.100'])
   future = client.compute(z, workers={z: '127.0.0.1',
                                   x: '192.168.0.1:9999'})
   future = client.compute(z, workers={(x, y): ['192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.101:9999']})
   ```
2. Use [Resources](https://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html) concept. You can specify available resources to worker like:

   ```
   dask-worker scheduler:8786 --resources "CAN_PROCESS_QUEUE_ALICE=2"
   ```

   and specify required resources like

   ```
   client.submit(aggregate, processed, resources={'CAN_PROCESS_QUEUE_ALICE': 1})
   ```

   or

   ```
   z = some_dask_object.map_parititons(func)
   z.compute(resources={tuple(y.__dask_keys__()): {'CAN_PROCESS_QUEUE_ALICE': 1})
   ```